# Forking an application to two instances - one or two database instances?

Tags: java, sql, database-design

We have a working application based on JDBC and Oracle Database. There is a requirement to create another instance of the application. Newly created instance of the application would be designed for a trusted client of the company and the fact of accessing the same application server does not pose a problem.

And here our doubt arises, because we have three options how to accomplish the task:

1. Deploy another instance of the application and create a separate database.
2. Modify the application to access two seperate databases
3. Modify the application and the database to support "an instance" - every table would have another column that defines which instance we are working on

There are some factors to consider: change effort, ease of maintaining (patching the application and the database, storing in the repository, need of keeping two versions up-to-date).

I know that there is no clear and obvious answer to this question, but I just wanted to hear your opinion, see pros and cons of each solution and most importantly know potential pitfalls that I do not see in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if 2 your instances should see separate set of data the easiest way is to create 2 separate (by identical) DB schemas and configure first instance to work with first schema and second instance to work with second schema.

If both instances should see the same data just configure them to work with the same DB.

In any case do not modify your code to support stupid requirement like this one. If you received one such requirements you will receive more in future (I am not a fortune teller. I just have some experience...). I think that the last thing you want to to change your application every time you get yet another deployment requirement.

Comment: Well, the data for each instance will be completely seperate, but who knows, maybe one day in fact we will need to have some cross-instance access. But in fact, the idea with schemas, not databases might be a good solution.

Comment: @starko - Don't try to predict the future here. Doing extra work because you "might" need to access it later is a dangerous way of deciding how complex to make your codebase. Stick to the simple thing here and just create another DB instance. Realistically, if your code is already right, that should just mean configuring a different data source, which should be trivial.